# How to prevent OnCustomDraw of CTreeCtrl from painting Default painting on my painting

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I created a CTreeCtrl but I need to mark some of the items in red colored hollow box.
So I created the function OnCustomDraw and drew a red colour box around the item. The red box is appearing but the text part and image parts are drawn on top of the red box so some part of the box cannot be seen. I guess the default painting is overriding my painting. Can anyone tell me how my painting will be over the default painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you should be painting on the correct stage.  `CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT` seems to be a good choice.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919569%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#CustomDraw_PaintCyclesEtc) you would find more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert an item (your draw possibly as a bitmap and your text as well) instead of updating just your draw.

Answer (score 0):

Set the item's custom draw flag: Before performing your custom drawing, you need to set the custom draw flag for the item you want to modify. This flag tells the `CTreeCtrl` to skip the default painting for that item.

Handle the `OnCustomDraw` event: Override the `OnCustomDraw` event handler for the `CTreeCtrl` control. This event is triggered when the control needs to be painted.

Perform your custom drawing: Within the `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` case of the `OnCustomDraw` event, you can perform your custom drawing for the specific item. This is where you have control over how the item is painted.

Return `CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT`: To prevent the default painting, you need to return `CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT` from the `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` case. This tells the `CTreeCtrl` to skip the default painting for the item you're handling.